# What should we do with locked questions that have answers providing inaccurate/wrong information?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

When we go to Stack Overflow, it's to find an answer about something we haven't mastered. When we choose the accepted answer, we expect to get something appropriate. If for any reason we get something bad, we can raise better answers and add comment to explain what's wrong with the accepted one and what's bad with the one we thing it is better. All that process serves next users and it is what makes Stack Overflow so excellent and so distinct from all other websites.

But when there are questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls#), where the accepted answer has very bad behavior (like does not check for second instance of a specific type) and we lose hours to debugging, Stack Overflow loses all its usefulness and credibility. Users who found bug in accepted answer can't help next visitors when the question is locked.

Also.. although it is written at the beginning ("LOCKED"), you should be aware that people never read things. On a long email, you are lucky if they read the 2 first lines. Also the "locked" text does not explain the proper exact reason. I think you should do something more descriptive and visually more evident. Like: answer is wrong and put the page background in red. But preferably, do nothing... let users do there job and the better answer will automatically be voted higher than the accepted one.

What do you think about it ?

Note: I think that sometimes you lock a question because an answer could be down voted so much that it could destroy people's reputation although they did answer with best intention. I wonder if question should either be destroyed permanently or if the answer should be locked (versus locking full question) to ensure people will not lose their reputation for a little mistake. But locking a full question removes all the possibilities for the so lovely automatic regulation system (reputation/points) that make Stack Overflow so useful and intelligent.

Comment: The answer isn't locked because the answer is incorrect. Locked questions exist only for historical reasons

Comment: "Also the "locked" text does not explain the proper exact reason."  What about it don't you feel is appropriate?  What do you think is missing from the lock description?

Comment: Historical reason? Sounds very vague to me. But mainly the question is locked with a very bad answer... you could see some answer later that correct it but people can't voted up that one because it is locked for "Historical" reason... What is the exact reason ?

Comment: My point was about that specific question but also on current design of stack overflow. I question myself about what good reason would make sense to lock a question when automatic regulation should take care of special cases.

Comment: @EricOuellet So did you keep reading past the first phrase?  It's locked because `it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.`

Comment: @Servy, this question has exactly other duplicate many times. Also this question has the same flavor has all questions I look every day. What make it off-topic ???

Comment: @EricOuellet It's too broad.  Way too broad.  If it was more specific about the exact requirements rather than asking for "all possible ways" then it could potentially be an appropriate question for the site.

Comment: @Servy, do a search on "WPF find control" ==> 4644 hits. Not enough. Yes this question is a little bit open. But it does not remove the fact that it should never be locked.

Comment: @Servy, searching for control by anything has a problematic of searching, not comparing. And you can easily see that by answers.

Comment: @EricOuellet The fact that you get a tons of results when searching doesn't mean that the question is appropriate.  If anything, in this case, it only clarifies just how broad this is.

Comment: @Servy, you let a question where so many people marked as helpful "LOCKED" and when a bug is in the answer. You want StackOverflow to loose all its reputation ??? People trust question voted up and accepted answer and voted up answer. How can we trust a site where they lock something wrong ???? At least delete it if it is so off-topic !!!

Comment: @Eric Calm down, we're here to help :) I do agree that there's a problem with locked questions providing harmful information. But I don't think outright deleting historical questions is the solution.

Comment: @EricOuellet The whole point of a question being locked is to specifically say that it is not an appropriate question, it isn't being maintained, it isn't representative of the community standards of quality, etc.

Comment: @Servy, add an option to mark question that should be deleted because it is locked but contain wrong accepted answer.

Comment: @EricOuellet If you feel that a locked question should be deleted the appropriate mechanism is to request it on meta.  If a mod agrees that the post should be deleted, they can delete it.

Comment: @Servy, ok. I calm down! I do want the best for stackOverflow and their users. Same as you !!!

Comment: @Servy, Perhaps, you can mixed some of my suggestion... When a question is marked as locked but contains bad accepted answer, we should be able to set a warning about it and the background should become more and more red with more people setting it as wrong accepted answer. Or anything else that could help people not fall in the same trap as I did.

Comment: @EricOuellet If a question is locked and does not contain particularly valuable content the solution is simply to delete it, not to keep it around while telling people not to use it.

Comment: @Servy, But who will delete it ? It should be people with hi power and it should advise the author, I think. It is a question of politeness. I'm sure the person who ask did it with the best intention. In fact I could have ask that type of question easily (An I personally like that question).

Comment: @Servy, and also the person who wrote the accepted answer had good intention (it work sometimes). We should not penalize those persons.

Comment: @EricOuellet I already answered that for you [in this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219869/what-should-we-do-with-locked-questions-that-have-answers-providing-inaccurate-w?noredirect=1#comment711811_219869)  The author can't even delete his own answer if he wanted, due to the lock.

Comment: @Servy, I understand that you lock question that open debate (like what is the best product...) but sometimes I think you close too quickly some good questions. I wonder if some people should not have some privileges removed or perhaps make some little changes or precisions to your restriction system (sorry for my bad English).

Comment: They're not good questions. In any event, this one wasn't closed quickly. It was locked after three and a half years.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks! Can we send email to the author asking him to delete it for the benefits of people ? Does he will loose all its related reputations for deleting it ?

Comment: @EricOuellet Apparently you didn't read my comment thouroughly.  Go re-read it.

Comment: @Servy, I click but nothing happen ???

Comment: @Servy, I found it. I will try it. But I think it is so hard (have to go to meta) that nobody else will ever do it and StackOverflow will stay with some bad questions. Although it rare, its not really something good!