# Locked question with bad accepted answer on stackOverflow --> can it be deleted or better unlocked?

Tags: support, specific-question, locked-questions

Following my question [here at meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219869/stackoverflow-question-locked-with-wrong-answer?noredirect=1#comment711816_219869), I wonder if you can delete the question [Wpf way to find controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls#) because the accepted answer is wrong. The answer contains bad code that would not do the job properly in many cases and would lead people to more trouble than help.

I consider a better solution to unlocked it (although it goes against some of your rules) because it was an appreciated one that contains very useful answers and code. But I can understand that it won't fit your strict rules.

Comment: What does that question even mean?  Are people losing their controls?  Is this a medical problem?

Comment: A question exists that is locked. He is suggesting that the answer provided is wrong and will cause problems to future visitors and wants it deleted. However, it is locked, so close votes are not allowed.

Comment: What would close votes do on an unlocked question @KevinB?

Comment: I don't know, i'm not the one asking! maybe i misinterpreted the comment.

Comment: *[humor fail]* ...

Answer (score 6):

That was a profoundly stupid way for someone to ask a rather banal question.

I edited it to be less open-ended and unlocked it.

Feel free to edit and/or down-vote the accepted answer.

Comment: ... or downvote and post a correct answer of your own.

Comment: It was not related to just that question. That was how it turned out. It was also about website design that would easily permits to manage those case on an easier way (than meta) which I think a lot of people will not do due to the little effort required to go to the meta website.

Comment: @Eric: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/what-if-the-answers-of-a-historical-locked-question-become-obsolete

Comment: @Shog9, I red it. But it is exactly the main reason why I wrote what I wrote. Who will take all the time to read that. Who will ask to re-open it. It could happen but if the effort is too big, people will not do it. My intention was not just to re-open that question. It was to bring to this author website a potential improvement on something that happen occasionally. This case is probably not the only one. But it's potentially the only one you ever eared about it because it take some effort to go to meta.

Comment: @Shog9, also, it will delayed any potential correction if the effort is too big. You could calculate that going to meta is easy but I think that for many people it will not.

Comment: You did. And it got done. And I don't think it was really all that hard. Locks are supposed to be rare, *because* they break things in this way - unless we start handing them out like candy, I don't think this will be a big problem.